# Pressure Notifications Not Displaying in bidvertiser

Tags: django, notifications, ads, vps

I am having an issue with the pressure notifications on my website. I have added the sw.js file to the root directory of my site, and I have selected a location for the notifications to display. However, when I open the site, only the text "by BidVertiser" is displayed in place of the ad.

I have checked the following:

```
The site is fully loaded.
There is not a lot of activity on the site.
There are not a lot of visitors to the site.
```

I have also tried the following:

```
Using a different location for the notifications.
Using different sizes and types of images for the notifications.
```

I am still having the same issue.